# How to use FormControl for multiselect using react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to reactjs. I am trying to use multi select using form control.

Below is my code:

```
handleIds(e){
  let id = null;
  if(e.target.value) {
    id = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  } else {
    id = null
  }
  this.state.Ids.push(id);
}

<FormGroup controlId="formQueryIds"
  validationState = {this.validateNotEmpty(this.state.queryIds)}>
 <ControlLabel>Query Ids</ControlLabel>
  {this.loadQueries()}
 <FormControl componentClass="select"
   placeholder="Select ids"
   onChange={this.handleIds}
   multiple>
  {this.state.items.map((item) => <option key={item.id}>{item.id}</option>)}
 </FormControl>
 <FormControl.Feedback />
</FormGroup>
```

Here items is an array of ids which is dynamically providing the option values.

The problem here is: for every single selection of option, it's triggering handleIds and adding the value to the array Ids[].

But when we unselect the option which we selected already, I am unable to trigger handleIds and remove the value from the array.

Is there a way to design to remove value from the array as soon it's unselected or instead of triggering handleIds for every selection, just triggering once and provide all the selected values as an array?

Comment: About `this.state.Ids.push(id);`, you should be using `this.setState`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Daniel Reinoso . if I use this.setState I am getting below error                                                                                                                                                                  {"timestamp":"2018-06-28T20:57:40.734+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING